# White area around a div when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed background image (red part) but when I scroll the page, the div over has some white areas on the sides which hide the background

[White area on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLOF8.png)

[white areas on the sides after having scrolled below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvIlD.png)

css code of the background image

```
  #title {
  background: url('../res/red.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

css part of the div over

```
#text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #efeff5;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
}
```

html code

```
<div id="title">
      <div id="text">
        <math>
          <mfrac>
            <mi>2</mi>
            <mi>2</mi>
          </mfrac>
          = 1
        </math>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: replace the margin-top with padding-top ... and be sure to remove all the margin from the body

Comment: here is the fixed code : https://jsfiddle.net/1eo63vxd/4/ ... you have to also get rid of height:100%;